# Python code to extract C doc comments associated with functions

Tags: python, c, parsing, python-2.7

I'm doing some codebase analysis and I would like the presentation to include some of the information we keep in function name doc comments.

Is there any Python library that can help with extracting information in C including comments? I tried pycparser but swiftly realized it parses the output of cpp, which already strips comments. I also tried using ply to write my own but realized this is a crazy task + don't think I am up to it.

Comment: Depending on which preprocessor is used, it may accept an argument to keep comments. Look at the documentation or manual page for your preprocessor.

Comment: I've had to do the same and I ended up using a regex to find comments (which is a bit brittle I know) and then map line numbers, function definitions and comments.

Comment: You can use `libclang` with Python to find comments.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to use python? Why not use a purpose-built doc generator like [doxygen](http://doxygen.org)?

If this is not sufficient, you could post-process the HTML/XML using python to pick the stuff that you need.